# How can we account for elements that may move inside a 2D list/vector?

Tags: list, algorithm, vector, data-structures

I got this question from a programming challenge event but didn’t pass all the test cases. Here’s the question:

Imagine you’re playing Minecraft and using sand blocks to build stuff, you can add one block to any row horizontally (from left to right) and the block will fall vertically (from top to bottom) until it hits the bottom or another block. Your goal is to find the number of minimum and maximum moves to fill the first column, i.e., [min, max].

For example, we have a 4x4 space like this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1]], where 1 represents a stone block that cannot be moved.
```

The answer for the above example is [10, 12]. First you need to add 1 sand block to the last row and fill (3, 0). Then we add 2 blocks to the 1st and 3rd row respectively and fill (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), and (0, 2) in order. After that, we add 2 blocks, 1 block, and 2 blocks to 3rd/2nd/1st row and fill the first column, which gives us 10. To get the number of maximum move, we add two more blocks to 3rd row and fill the space at (2, 3) and (2, 4).

I tried to use a counter to count how many zeros we meet before meeting a stone block and keeped comparing with current_min/current_max to find the answer. However, this approach won't work for cases when we need to account for falling sand blocks.

Using the same example, my approach would get [10, 10] instead of [10, 12]. I was thinking if we can check if the row below is 0, add 1 to the answer and modify the space in place to account for the falling sand blocks. Can anyone provide some ideas on potential solution and possbily code as well? Thanks!

Comment: I clicked on your question expecting a C++ question, but I don't see one.  Instead, it looks like a data structures/algorithm question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Also please don't spam multiple unrelated language tags. If your question truly is language-agnostic, there's a specific tag for that. Otherwise only tag the language you're actually programming in. Different languages can (and do) have different behavior.

Comment: And if by "programming challenge event" you mean something like a so-called "competition" or "judge" site, then you have to remember that those sites are not any kind of learning or teaching resource. If your goal is to learn programming, or programming languages, such sites is the wrong way to go. Invest in books and take computer-science classes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and I have just edited my questions and tags to be more specific. I have computer science background but would like to learn how to solve some challenging problems like this one and use them to check/better my understanding.